# Error while adding elements from one xml file to new xml file

Tags: java, xml, jdom

HI,

Now i'm going through a project regarding xml manipulation. I want to rewrite the data from one xml file to another. I've attatched my coding and error showing in console. As i'm new to this project i don't know whether this concept is write or not.Could anybody help me to know about this problem?

Would appreciate any pointers..

coding:

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.jdom.Document;
import org.jdom.Element;
import org.jdom.JDOMException;
import org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder;

public class Test3 {
    static Document profile = new Document();
    static Element html     = new Element("html");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JDOMException {
        try{
            profile.setRootElement(html);
        String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><myhtml> <body> <h1 align=\"center\">Profile</h1><hr /> <div class=\"centered\"> <table><tr><td><strong>Name: </strong></td> <td>A</td> </tr> <tr> <td><strong>Age: </strong></td> <td>23</td> <td>programmer</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Email: </strong></td><td>adfg@gmail.com</td></tr></table></div><hr /></body></myhtml>";
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.build(new StringReader(xml));
        listChildrenOrg(doc.getRootElement(), 0);
}
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

     private static void listChildrenOrg(Element root, int depth) {
        System.out.println(root.getName());
        List children = root.getChildren();
        System.out.println(children.size());
        Iterator iterator = children.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
             Element child = (Element) iterator.next();
             System.out.println(child);
             body.addContent(((Element)child.clone()).detach());
             listChildrenOrg(child, depth+1);
               }
}
}
```

output file is blured one..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>First Try</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">h1 { text-align: center; } div.centered {text-align: center;} div.centered table {margin: 0 auto; text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Body part</h1>
<hr />
</body>
<body> <h1 align="center">Profile</h1><hr /> 

<div class="centered"> 
<table><tr><td><strong>Name: </strong></td> 
<td>A</td> </tr> 
<tr> <td><strong>Age: </strong></td> 
<td>23</td> 
<td>programmer</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Email: </strong></td><td>adfg@gmail.com</td></tr></table></div>
<hr /></body><h1 align="center">Profile</h1><hr />

<div class="centered"> 
<table><tr><td><strong>Name: </strong></td> 
<td>A</td> </tr> 
<tr> <td><strong>Age: </strong></td> 
<td>23</td> 
<td>programmer</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Email: </strong></td>
<td>adfg@gmail.com</td></tr></table></div>

<table><tr><td><strong>Name: </strong></td> 
<td>A</td> </tr> 
<tr> <td><strong>Age: </strong></td> 
<td>23</td> 
<td>programmer</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Email: </strong></td>
<td>adfg@gmail.com</td></tr></table>
<tr><td><strong>Name: </strong></td> 

<td>A</td> </tr>
<td><strong>Name: </strong></td>
<strong>Name: </strong>
<td>A</td>
<tr> <td><strong>Age: </strong></td> 
<td>23</td> 
<td>programmer</td></tr>
<td><strong>Age: </strong></td>

<strong>Age: </strong>
<td>23</td><td>programmer</td>
<tr><td><strong>Email: </strong></td><td>adfg@gmail.com</td></tr>
<td><strong>Email: </strong></td><strong>Email: </strong>
<td>adfg@gmail.com</td><hr />
</html>
```

Comment: i added xml as a string inside main function itself!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to clone and detach the child from its parent element before adding it to the new parent:

```
html.addContent(((Element)child.clone()).detach());
```

Comment: Thank you for your support.It is working,but outputfile is blured.I've added output xml as updated question.Could you please go through that...

Comment: Hi, take a look at your input and output. Your recursion is unnecessary. If you want to add a node (and all of its content) as a child to another element, you just really need to do only one addContent (after you've cloned and detached the original node).
However, this is another kind of problem; I've answered to your original question with my solution, which works. Then you've edited your question, and now your issue looks very different. I think this is not the right way to proceed. Have a great day.

Comment: Hi @javanna,actually i got a mistake about that. Till this time i was working with that recursion.That's why i thought related to it.Now only-when you said about this-i get clarity about that.Really thank you @javanna.That's very kind of you.Have a nice day..

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here:

```
Element child = (Element) iterator.next();
System.out.println(child);
html.addContent(child);
```

`child` is **reference** to the `body` element of the original xml document. Its parent is `myhtml`
You cannot add this as child of another new element in this way.

You need to create a new element for the new xml document. I suggest you to study on "Reference" in Java.

Comment: Thank you @Sarwar Erfan... Could you give me or suggest a material to study about it.

Comment: Thanks @Sarwar Erfan..I went through the material that you have sent.It was very useful one.But still i couldn't solve my problem. I want elements with attributes from one xml file(body) to new xml file.Now i am using JDOM parser.I tried all methods i.e. addContent(),setContent() etc. But i couldn't manage to get the output. If you know about that could you help me to solve this problem?